# MonoTouch.Dialog DialogViewController Rowheight not maintained when orientation change

Tags: uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

In my Xamarin project, I have used DailogViewController.

Using this, I have set the root elements and height both.

When I run the application, it works fine and the height (35f) which I set.

But when orientation change, in debug console, I see 35f as row-height, but In View, it is bigger than 35f.

The first output is like below image which is correct,

[image]

But after orientation change, it is displaying bigger size, but in console, the value of row-height is displaying 35f.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated to resolve this discrepancy in UI.

I debug it out more, It is resetting its size to 63f.

After more debugging, I found out, if we are using **"BadgeElement" class** for creating cell with ***Image+text***, then only it is happening. Any way to set static height for **"BadgeElement"**

Comment: So you solved it by setting static height for "BadgeElement"?

Comment: no, it didn't work.

Comment: It works, when I follow the traditional approach for creating data source and delegates as it is done in native iOS, and by setting those changes I was able to solve this issue.